# Assembly language addw vs addw vs

Tags: assembly, x86-64, att

What does the suffix refer to? The size of the source value, the size of the destination?

What would happen if you did:

1. `addw (%r8) %rax`. Would it add one byte, two bytes, three bytes? Interpreted as signed or unsigned?
2. Say $eax = 0x0000FFFF. What would the result be after `addw $1 %ax`? Would eax be 0x00000000 or 0x00010000?

Comment: 1. is a syntax error because RAX is an 8-byte register, incompatible with word (2-byte) operand size from the `w` suffix.  Also because it's missing a comma.

Comment: 2's complement addition is the same binary operation as unsigned addition; x86 ALU operations set both CF and OF; it's up to you do decide which flags to look at for unsigned vs. signed overflow.

Comment: For question 2, the result is eax = 0, because changing ax doesn’t affect the upper bits of eax.

Comment: assembly language is defined by the assembler, the tool you are using, what tool are you using?

Comment: w is the operand size.  Of all operands generally.

Comment: @old_timer: I tagged this question with [tag:att], which is the assembly-language syntax being used; the two examples are enough to unambiguously determine that it's AT&T syntax.  (Except that it requires commas between operands).  There are multiple assemblers that support AT&T syntax, but they're all compatible (except for possibly some rare corner cases in clang vs. GAS).  So I don't see the point of your comment; it's like if you'd commented "what language are you using" on a C question.  There aren't different versions of AT&T syntax.

Comment: ATT is not an assembly language, it is simply a style between result on the left or right.  The assembly language is defined by the assembler, ATT vs Intel is only a wee tiny part of that.  You in particular have enough experience to know the history of the assembly language with the popular tools over the decades and how incompatible it is be it intel vs intel or att vs att.  Putting the w on the end is not universal so it is specific to an assembler of course and perhaps a subset of assemblers.

Comment: syntax questions need to specify the assembler, not just the target.  gas, masm, tasm, basm, nasm, fasm, a86, etc. and ideally version.